# Extracting exact table data from PDF

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, data-extraction, boxable

I am trying to extract each row of my table from a pdf file I created before.

The problem  I have, is that empty cells, which I thought would be saved as 'null', are ignored, and not even read as space characters.

[image]

[image: extracted from PDF]

I extract the content from my PDF via this method:

```
    public final ArrayList<String> extractLines(final File pdf) throws IOException {
    try (PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(pdf)) {
        PDFTextStripper strip = new PDFTextStripper();
        String txt = strip.getText(doc);
        String[] arr = txt.split("\n");
        final ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(arr));
        return lines;
    }
}
```

Is it even possible to extract the data with whitespaces?

If so, with PDFBox? Or a different method?

EDIT:

Cannot get traprange to work, simple test:

```
File e = new File("C:/Users/Test/Downloads/a.pdf");

    List<Table> t = new PDFTableExtractor().setSource(e).extract();
    System.out.println(t.get(0).toString());
```

Only gives me:

[image]

Could it have to do with the form of my table?

My table:

[image]

Comment: *"Is it even possible to extract the data with whitespaces?"* - most likely there are no white spaces in those empty cells. Have you tried Ctrl-A?

Comment: make sure you're using the latest PDFBox version. Traprange uses 2.0.6 but we're at 2.0.25. The exception happens in the initialization of the stripper.

Comment: but 2.0.6 doesnt exist on the PDFBox site? Only 2.0.25 and Alpha 3.0

Comment: If you're building with maven then it exists. You need to override the version or fork the project and modify its pom.xml

Comment: the pom of traprange uses pdfbox 1.8.9, changing it to newer version breaks the code :/

Comment: This one https://github.com/thoqbk/traprange/blob/master/pom.xml shows 2.0.6 .

Comment: I looked at an older 1.8 version. This might be related to a java version number that has a single component, e.g. "17" instead of "17.0.1", enter "java -version".

Comment: got it to work, however traprange cant seem to differentiate my 1st and 2nd column, and puts them together :/ – 

so i got "12/1" instead of 1, 2/1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240826/discussion-between-dahlin-and-tilman-hausherr).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with my own solution.

Since I have a 2D ArrayList, I each have a list containing  a row of the table.

Now I save the position of the non empty cells (only one is not empty per row at any time).

I save it in a meta data field of the PDF and load this field to get the positions back.

Answer (score 2):

The solution needs custom algorithm to complete the task. Please check [this solution](https://gist.github.com/beldaz/8ed6e7473bd228fcee8d4a3e4525be11) for custom PDFTableStripper.

Another great solution has been implemented by [Tho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/875775/tho) which could be found at [traprage](https://github.com/thoqbk/traprange). It can extract the null data of a particular cell.

Comment: I tried traprage, however I cant even get a simple test to work, I added it to my question

Comment: got it to work, however traprange cant seem to differentiate my 1st and 2nd column, and puts them together 
so i got "12/1" instead of 1, 2/1